# Process List<String> with synchronous delay after flatMap?

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor

Hey I just started to dive into reactive programming and I can't figure out how to process a `List<String>` in a synchronous way after `flatMap`.

What I am trying to achieve:

1. Get domain list from external service
2. Filter out existing domains in database
3. Make another http request to external service to get domain info. These calls **should** be executed in a **synchronous** way with `Duration.ofSeconds(new Random().nextInt(5))` delay applied one after another, like `Thread.sleep` and not in parallel way.
4. Store new domain data into database

```
client.fetchDomainList() // Flux<DomainListResponse>
.flatMap(response -> Flux.fromIterable(response.getDomainList()))
.filter(hostname -> ! domainRepository.existsByHostname(hostname))
.collectList()

// this next bit is sketchy. 
// flatMap will doesn't work here (in my mind) 
// because it will apply delay in parallel way
.map(list -> Flux.fromIterable(list)
    .map(hostname -> client.fetchDomainInfo(hostname)
        .delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(new Random().nextInt(3))))
    .map(domainInfoResponse -> {
        return new Domain();
    })
)

.flatMap(s -> { // s -> Flux<Domain> here. Should be simply Domain
 // save into database?
})
```

Comment: Do you need the domains to be filtered sequentially?

Comment: @adnan_e not really, I can filter them out in any order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to wrap that synchronous call in a `Mono.fromCallable` which yields 0-1 items depending on whether the condition is met or not.

```
Mono<T> checkDomain(T domain) {
   // consider adding (if appropriate) subscribeOn to switch to another scheduler suitable for this, such as parallel() perhaps
   return Mono.fromCallable(() -> {
      boolean filterMatches = ... your blocking HTTP request ...
      return filterMatches;
   }).flatMap(filterMatches -> filterMatches ? Mono.just(domain) : Mono.empty());
}
...

client.fetchDomainList() // Flux<DomainListResponse>
    .flatMap(response -> Flux.fromIterable(response.getDomainList()))
    // we are mapping 1 domain to 0-1 domain, depending on whether the condition is met.
    .delayElements(/* your Duration */)
    .flatMap(domain -> checkDomain(domain))
```

Docs for `Flux.delayElements`:

```
/**
 * Delay each of this {@link Flux} elements ({@link Subscriber#onNext} signals)
 * by a given {@link Duration}. Signals are delayed and continue on the
 * {@link Schedulers#parallel() parallel} default Scheduler, but empty sequences or
 * immediate error signals are not delayed.
 *
 * <p>
 * <img class="marble" src="doc-files/marbles/delayElements.svg" alt="">
 *
 * @param delay duration by which to delay each {@link Subscriber#onNext} signal
 * @return a delayed {@link Flux}
 * @see #delaySubscription(Duration) delaySubscription to introduce a delay at the beginning of the sequence only
 */
public final Flux<T> delayElements(Duration delay) {
    return delayElements(delay, Schedulers.parallel());
}
```

I made a small PoC to test this out myself and came up with the following

```
    static Mono<Integer> verifyDomain(Integer t) {
        return Mono.fromCallable(() -> {
            Thread.sleep(100); // simulate HTTP request
            return t % 2 == 0; // is even?
        }).flatMap(condition -> condition ? Mono.just(t) : Mono.empty());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Flux.fromStream(Stream.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10))
                .delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(5))
                .flatMap(i -> verifyDomain(i))
                .subscribe(i -> System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now() + " - " + i));

        Thread.sleep(100000); // just to stay alive
    }
```

And the output is as expected:

```
2021-10-19T16:58:28.644437500 - 2
2021-10-19T16:58:38.898397500 - 4
2021-10-19T16:58:49.130059 - 6
2021-10-19T16:58:59.376111100 - 8
2021-10-19T16:59:09.603982600 - 10
```

Comment: I need to execute domain info calls with sequential delay. Like `Thread.sleep`. One call finished, wait, another call. I can just make it straight blocking way, but I want to understand how to do that reactive way. I updated the question. I have API request limits, like 30 calls in 1 minute. By fanning out 100 requests with flatMap and applying delay later it will send them all in 5 seconds.

Comment: See my edit, although I haven't verified it myself, yet.

Comment: @message I also added a small PoC showing. Although if the delay is all you were looking for, then the Flux.filter from your original piece + Flux.delayElements is enough.

Comment: I guess I was adding blocking behavior to non-blocking environment. That was dumb. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @adnan_e your PoC might be biased by the fact that it blocks in the `fromCallable`. Perhaps it can use `Mono.delay` as the db simulator ?

Comment: @message `concatMap` instead of `flatMap(this::verifyDomain)` might be a good way of ensuring verifyDomain isn't called until the previous one has finished